# Passing a variable within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Whilst the below related to a child stored procedure I believe the issue to be something to do with passing a value within the same procedure..

Issue:

I want to return a value from a user defined function I call from stored procedure.
If I hardcode the line
`SELECT @SiteImage = ImageName FROM TblImages WHERE SITEID = @SiteIDOriginal` to be
`SELECT @SiteImage = ImageName FROM TblImages WHERE SITEID = 'HARDCODED_SITE_ID'`then it passes back what I want.

I believe I am passing the correct variable though before but need some guidance as to where it 'drops' the value.

In the 'Parent' stored procedure I request:

```
dbo.GetPropertyImage(UPPER(@SITEID)) as SitePhoto
```

Then I do as follows and want to return the value @SiteImage to this line, the passback works as I mentioned I've tested this via hard coding.

```
USE [cording]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetPropertyImage]    Script Date: 05/18/2015 09:17:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPropertyImage]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @SiteID varchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @SiteImage varchar(100)
    DECLARE @SiteIDOriginal varchar(100)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

    SELECT @SiteIDOriginal=PemcoShortCode  FROM iBasePropertyDetails WHERE PemcoShortCode=@SiteID

    SELECT @SiteImage = ImageName FROM TblImages WHERE SITEID = @SiteIDOriginal
    --SiteID = @SiteIDOriginal

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @SiteImage

END
```

Comment: i not sure sql-server have this rules or not, in mysql, stored procedure cannot be call by another stored procedure, only stored  function can be call by stored procedure

Comment: It calls it from the parent and returns a value but only if I hardcode SiteIDOriginal. So I believe the faults trying to get the value SiteIDOriginal

Comment: Excuse me but it is not clear to me where the issue is: do you have any error or simply it doesn't respond what you were expecting?

Comment: Try executing the `udf `with the value of `UPPER(@SITEID)` and see if it returns any value. Also, edit your question to include the calling stored procedure as well

Comment: I don't get anything passed back (unless I hardcode SiteIDOriginal)

Comment: `SELECT PemcoShortCode  FROM iBasePropertyDetails WHERE PemcoShortCode=@SiteID INTO @SiteIDOriginal;` ?

Comment: SQL says not the right syntax but certainly the right idea.

Comment: execute the incriminated function in studio manager and add a print between the two select to check if you're getting what you wanted (PRINT @SiteIDOriginal); you could also check for upper/lower chars, depending on the collation you have

Comment: Your syntax seems to be correct, so the problem is probably in the data returned from the udf. If it's not returning the data you expect, then you should search for the problem there.

Comment: @YuYenkan you're post nudge me into thinking and the answer is this... SELECT [@SiteIDOriginal] = ID FROM iBasePropertyDetails WHERE PemcoShortCode=[@SiteID]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE [Database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetImage]
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@SiteID varchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @SiteImage varchar(100)
    DECLARE @SiteIDOriginal varchar(100)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

     SELECT [@SiteIDOriginal] = ID FROM iBasePropertyDetails WHERE PemcoShortCode=[@SiteID] 

SELECT @SiteImage = ImageName FROM TblImages WHERE SITEID = @SiteIDOriginal


    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @SiteImage

END
```